# The request for url passes 2 times, although it should 1 time

Tags: swift, swift3

The result of the work should be a text message to the user, which for some reason comes 2 times, the Java code from the Android app sends 1 sms, so problems with the server are excluded

```
 let url2=URL(string:"url="+PhoneTextField.text!)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let userPasswordString = "user:pass"
let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!
let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
config.urlCache = nil
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
let session = URLSession.init(configuration: config)

    let task=session.dataTask(with: url2!){
        ( data, response, error) in
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
          self.dataStringJSon=dataString as String?
        if(self.dataStringJSon!=="User not found"){

        }else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MySecondSecreen") as! UIViewController;
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
            }

        }

    }

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable caching with a session configuration

```
config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
config.urlCache = nil
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help

Comment: After disabling basic auth on the server,the queries duplicated ceased